# Add an object in an embedded data model using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new with mongo and mongoose and I'd like to know how we can add, delete or edit an object in the database when we have an embedded data model as follow :

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    local            : {
        email        : String,
        password     : String,
    },

    houses             : [

        {
            phone_numbers : [ {number: String} ],
            adresse         : String,

        }

     ]

    });


    module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

For example, I would like to add a new "house" to my user.

So I tried :

```
            User.findById(req.user.id, function(err, user){

                user.houses.adresse = 'TEST';
                user.save();

             });
```

But it does not seem to work and I didn't find how to do that in mongoose docs. Any idea on how I could accomplish that ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can separate model for readability, and you can use `House` model to add sub docs to `User` like;

**User.js**

```
var House = require("House");

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    email : String,
    password : String,
    houses : [ House.schema ]

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

**House.js**

```
var houseSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    phone_numbers : [ String ],
    adresse         : String,

});


module.exports = mongoose.model('House', houseSchema);
```

In your controller;

```
var User = require("models/User");
var House = require("models/House");

......


User.findById(req.user.id, function(err, user){

    var houseModel = new House();
    houseModel.adresse = "TEST";
    user.houses.push(houseModel);
    user.save();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//Craete an object and assign it the existing embedded doc.
var item = { houses: req.user.houses };
// add your new address into the existing object
item.houses.push({adresse:'Test'})

// $set below updates the whole document along with your new address
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, { $set: item }, function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
      callback(err, undefined);
  } else if (result) {
      callback(err, result);
  }
});
```